# simple C++ functions

Tags: c++, function

Ok so im sure im doing something stupid :D

i have a function:

```
int wordFunc(string a){
    std::ifstream inp;
    inp.open(a, std::ios::in);
    if (inp.is_open()){
        std::string word;
        unsigned long wordCount = 0;
        while(!inp.eof()){
            inp >> word;
            while(word.length() > 0){
                wordCount++;
            }
            inp.close();
        }
        return wordCount;
    }
}
```

the string is a user input file.txt - its set to be C:\Dump\user.txt right now

when i call the code with:

```
int main(){
    string file;
    int words = 0;
    file = "C:\\Dump\\user.txt";

    int a = wordFunc(file, words);
    cout << "Words: " << a << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The console just halts - I havnt coded anything in C++ in many a year so im definitely rusty - any help?

EDIT
With the help of some kind sould I ended up going like this

```
unsigned long wordFunc(const std::string& a){
    std::ifstream inp(a);
    system("cls");
    unsigned long wordCount = 0;
    std::string word;
    while(inp >> word)
    {
        wordCount++;
    }
    return wordCount;
}
```

For the function - should have posted an update

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct interface?  In the main program you call wordFunc with two arguments (file and word), and the function has just one argument (a).

Comment: Yea - i caught that too - it was definitely the while loop

Comment: Might as well be haha - im doing this random project for a friend - no deployments - This is what i get for mentioning that i had taken some cpp classes in college - i have the old txt books broken out and everything - feels like sophmore yr all over again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is this:

```
        while(word.length() > 0){
            wordCount++;
        }
```

This loops forever. You probably mean

```
        if(word.length() > 0){
            wordCount++;
        }
```

Comment: HA - i knew it was something redic - now im only counting 2 words but i can prob figure that out

Comment: @Hazy, it's because you're closing the file inside the read loop which means only one line is read - that, in conjuction with a misunderstanding as to when the EOF flag is set, is why you'll only ever get `2` as a return value. Once you fix that, there's a few other things you might want to look at (see my answer).

Answer (score 1):

You have quite a few problems there.

---

As another poster commented, the line:

```
while (word.length() > 0)
```

will loop forever, and you need to change it to:

```
if (word.length() > 0)
```

---

You mix integers and unsigned longs inappropriately. The `wordCount` and `a` variables, and the return value from `wordFunc()` should be the same.

---

You have the `inp.close()` *inside* the reading loop rather than outside where it belongs. This means it will close the file after processing the first line.

---

You also have the return statement inside the `if` statement meaning that you have a syntax error, not returning anything in one execution path (the one where the file couldn't be opened).

You need to swap the `return` and the closing brace that follows it.

This also means that the `wordCount` variable will have to be declared outside of the `if` statement as well (at the top level of the function).

---

I think `fstream::open()` takes a `char*` rather than a string so you should recode it as:

```
inp.open (a.c_str(), std::ios::in);
```

---

Your call to `wordFunc()`, with two parameters, doesn't match the prototype, which only has one.

---

There's some extraneous variables, such as `words` in `main()`.

---

The last word is counted *twice* because the EOF flag is only set once you try to read *beyond* the end of the file. You can fix that with a simple modification to the `if` statement that increments `wordCount`:

```
if ((!inp.eof()) && (word.length() > 0)) {
```

---

With all those changes made, you end up with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

unsigned long wordFunc (std::string str) {
    unsigned long wordCount = 0;
    std::ifstream inp;

    inp.open(str.c_str(), std::ios::in);
    if (inp.is_open()) {
        std::string word;
        while (!inp.eof()) {
            inp >> word;
            if ((!inp.eof()) && (word.length() > 0)) {
                wordCount++;
            }
        }
        inp.close();
    }
    return wordCount;
}

int main() {
    std::string file;
    file = "user.txt";
    unsigned long a = wordFunc(file);
    std::cout << "Words: " << a << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice. But I'd probably switch back to returning an int, and return `-1` on failure to open a file. I'd then invert the `if` so you end up with `if(!inp.is_open()){ return -1}`, and the rest of the logic is reduced one indent level.

Answer (score 1):

C++ already has functions in the standard library to do most of what you're after, so you can just do something like:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

int main() { 
    std::ifstream in("user.txt");

    std::cout << "Words: " 
              << std::distance(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(in),
                               std::istream_iterator<std::string>());
    return 0;
}
```

Gotta love code that needs five headers for three executable statements!

If you do insist on doing the counting yourself, I'd do something like:

```
std::ifstream in("user.txt");

std::string word;

while (in >> word)
    ++wordCount;

std::cout << "Words: " << wordCount;
```